# How to obtain enrollment certificate from CA in PHP

Tags: php, certificate

I'm writing a service that is supposed to receive DER format PKCS#10 certificate request in Base64 encoding from mobile device and then return certificates obtained  from CA.

I'm trying to use "https://CA-server/certsrv/mscep/mscep.dll?operation=PKIOperation&Message=urlencoded request"

```
     $ca_link_device="https://..../certsrv/mscep/mscep.dll";
     $URL=$ca_link_device."?operation=PKIOperation&Message=".urlencode($BinarySecurityToken)."=";
     $ch3 = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
     curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     $cert = curl_exec($ch3);
```

but the data that is returned contains empty envelope. I'm most probably doing something really dumb, but unfortunately my knowledge in certificate management is close to zero. I have been trying to google around, but there are so many technical documents around that I don't know from where to start and what is relevant to me and what is not.

All help much appreciated.

Edit: According to one documentation I should wrap my PKCS10 request into PKCS7. According to Microsoft PKCS10 should be fine and PKCS7 is only used for certificate renewal. Who to believe?

Comment: What does empty envelope mean?

Comment: empty container - 522 bytes of binary data. It might be also misconfigured NDES.

Comment: From event logs I got: "The Network Device Enrollment Service cannot retrieve required information, such as the transaction ID, message type, or signing certificate, from the client's PKCS7 message (0x8009310b).  ASN1 bad tag value met."

Comment: I added bounty to this question. I would like to get PHP sample how to wrap PKCS#10 request into PKCS#7 that would be acceptable to CA server. OR if it possible to conf. CA server to accept direct PKCS#10 request.

Comment: Which CA server are you using?

Comment: This question doesnt give much of anything in the way of helping us help you. What driver? What documentation? It is too localized otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the end we just droped the mscep.dll approach and used curl to directly send POST with needed parameters to ...certsrv/certfnsh.asp page. Then we parsed the returned HTML and obtained the link for certificate download.

Not a nice solution, but worked for us.